# Url Amigavel .htaccess com problema

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Eu tenho o seguinte arquivo .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

ErrorDocument 404 /erro404
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rota=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Eu estou tentando colocar uma condição que quando o usuario entrar na pagina site.com/editor ele vá para a pasta /editor em vez do index. Eu tentei do seguinte modo sem sucesso:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

ErrorDocument 404 /erro404
RewriteRule editor /editor/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rota=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dá erro ou not found?

Comment: Não, ele carrega o índex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta a flag `[L]`, ficando assim:

```
RewriteRule editor /editor/index.php [L]
```

Esta flag significa "last" (última). Quer dizer que, se a regra combinar, não verificará as outras. O Apache processa estas regras como se fosse um `switch` de uma linguagem de programação e a flag `[L]` funciona como se fosse o `break`.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.