# Problema de URL amigável com subpasta fixa

Tags: apache, url-amigável

Estou tendo um problema com httaccess ao incluir uma subpasta fixa.

O intuito é ter um pasta em frente ao domínio do site. Exemplo: `www.meudominio.com.br/guest/500` fazer relação com a página `www.meudominio.com.br/guest?id=500`.

Porém essa regra funciona apenas com `www.meudominio.com.br/guest` e não funciona com os demais.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule  ^guest/([^\.]+) guest.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Com o código anterior, o encaminhamento até funcionou, mas creio que deu algum erro no servidor, pois não carregou nenhum arquivo (de css até img).

Comment: essa pergunta te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55315/url-amigavel-htaccess-com-problema?rq=1

Comment: Tentei usar o exemplo acima e não deu certo. O que preciso é o htaccess funcione somente quando a url tiver direcionada no www.meudominio.com.br/guest/{GET}.